# React / Redux - losing state when direct to other route

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm a newbie to web development. I'm using react and redux to create a card component, but when I click the logo on the navbar to redirect to home route (/), everything disappear. Does anyone know which part of my code is wrong or missing? What I expected is everything staying there when spam clicking the logo navlink.

My code is on the sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-fermi-ix595?file=/src/components/Cards/Cards.js

Your advice are highly appreciated.

Comment: Not able to open the sandbox code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read about `splice` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/splice).

`splice` modify original array, so you should create a copy e.g. by spread operator, or use a [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/slice) method.

```
  const cardsContentCopy = [...cardsContent];
  const cardsContentFirstTwo = cardsContentCopy.splice(0, 2);
  const cardsContentRest = cardsContentCopy.splice(0, 3);
```

or

```
  const cardsContentFirstTwo = cardsContent.slice(0, 2);
  const cardsContentRest = cardsContent.slice(2);
```